# Replacing blocked YouTube video with external link

Tags: youtube, adblock, ublock-origin, ublock, palemoon

Is it possible to show link to YouTube video instead of completely erasing the YT iframe using *uBlock Origin*? Will it be treated (and blocked) as `3p-frame` or `3p` by dynamic filters, and thus blocked later, or not?

Comment: What browser are you using? It might be possible with userscripts.

Comment: Pale Moon + Arch Linux

Comment: That's a new one on me... let me do some research.

Comment: Perhaps [Greasemonkey for Pale Moon](https://github.com/janekptacijarabaci/greasemonkey/releases/tag/3.31.4Fork)? I'll look into it. Would be nice to do it without installing new addon though.